# Xamarin forms: Selected picture is not showing in UI from gallery and camera for IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, camera, gallery

**Complete Scenario**

I have an add icon on one page, it will show camera and gallery options when tap. If choose the camera, I will open another content page and open camera there. But the captured picture is not showing in the UI. Same for the gallery, selected image from the gallery is not showing in UI. This feature is working fine in android and not working in IOS.

**Codes**

`When click add icon`

```
string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, "Camera", "Gallery");
            if (action == "Camera")
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NewTweetPage("Camera"));
            }
            else if (action == "Gallery")
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NewTweetPage("Gallery"));
            }
```

`When entering next page`

```
public NewTweetPage(String medium)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (medium == "Camera" )
            {
                OpenMyCamera(); 
            }
            else if(medium == "Gallery")
            {
                OpenMygallery();
            }
        }

public async void OpenMyCamera()
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Camera", "No camera available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    AllowCropping = true
                });

                if (_mediaFile == null)
                    return;
                tweetPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    isPicture = true;
                    return _mediaFile.GetStream();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
            }
        }



public async void OpenMygallery()
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Gallery", ":( No photos available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

                if (_mediaFile == null)
                    return;
                tweetPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    isPicture = true;
                    return _mediaFile.GetStream();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
            }
        }
```

The same code is working fine in profile page part, but in that case, there is no page navigation, everything is happening on the same page.

Don't know what is the problem with the current code, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Putting navigation commands in the constructor can cause issues. I would recommend putting them in the `OnAppearing` override. Also, instead of having a `try...catch` around a large section of code, you should handle null-checks or similar in code.

Comment: @Tom Your comment fix my issue, please post it as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting navigation commands in the constructor can cause issues. I would recommend putting them in the `OnAppearing` override. Also, instead of having a `try...catch` around a large section of code, you should handle null-checks or similar in code.